# Tabular alignment inside theorem environment problem

Tags: tabularx, theorems, alignment

I am trying to add a tabular environment inside a theorem environment and there seems to be a sort of clash. The title and the table just get automatically horizontally aligned and remain stuck together across displaying transformations.

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3in]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm, tabularx, stackrel,amsmath, amssymb,xcolor}


\newtheorem{argument}{Argument} \theoremstyle{definition}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{argument}
        \begin{tabular}{rl}
            &$\stackrel[]{\emph{Option 1}}{\text{Sanji lives in Calgary}}$ \textcolor{blue}{or} $\stackrel[]{\emph{Option 2}}{\text{Sanji lives in Edmonton}}$ \\
            &We negagate option 2\\
            $\therefore$& Sanjgiv lives in Calgary (Option 1).
        \end{tabular}
    \end{argument}
\end{document}
```

produces the following output
[image]

But I am expecting the following output
[image]

I have tried surrounding the tabular with a `center` environnement, also tried adding `vspace{}` around the block, with no success. Anyone have any ideas of how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Add `\leavevmode` before the `center`  environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to start the `argument` environment with *something* (`\mbox` or `\leavevmode`) and then insert a blank line (or paragraph break) to have the `tabular` set on its own line):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,xcolor}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{argument}{Argument}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{argument}
  \mbox{}% or \leavevmode
  
  \begin{tabular}{rl}
                 & \begin{tabular}[b]{@{} c @{}}
                   \emph{\small Option 1} \\
                   Sanji lives in Calgary
                 \end{tabular} \textcolor{blue}{or}
                 \begin{tabular}[b]{@{} c @{}}
                   \emph{\small Option 2} \\
                   Sanji lives in Edmonton
                 \end{tabular} \\
                 & We negagate option 2 \\
    $\therefore$ & Sanjgiv lives in Calgary (Option 1).
  \end{tabular}
\end{argument}

\end{document}
```